# Connecting to a computer remotely

Tags: tcp, winsock

I found a tutorial that shows you how to create server and client programs, and make them communicate over a network.

http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_1.shtm

I can make a client program connect to, for example, 192.168.0.4 on my local network, and I can make it connect to 74.125.225.96. But what if I wanted to make it communicate with 192.168.0.4 on the network of 74.125.225.96, instead of just the default server on 74.125.225.96? I'm having a difficult time finding the answer with Google.

Is there even a way to do this? If not, then how are Gnutella and Bittorrent, able to connect computers directly together to share files?

Comment: Surely Albert Einstein can figure it out? Can't be more difficult than relativity...

Comment: I think you're a bit confused on how DNS works. An `A record` such as www.example.com., is bound to a specific IP Address. That DNS record has no knowledge, internally, or externally, of any network associated with that records IP binding. It's a one-to-one relationship between the name, `www.example.com` = `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Ah, ok. Is a remote IP address also bound to a specific local address?

Comment: No, it's not. All the DNS host record does is resolve any requests for www.example.com to a specific external IP address. When the server that is bound to that external IP address receives the request, it's up to that server to resolve any internal bindings. Point being, what you're asking to do isn't possible. You can't say, I want to go to `www.example.com:192.168.0.4`, because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are asking, 74.125.225.96 would have to be assigned to a router that is configured to forward inbound connections on the target server port to the machine that is running 192.168.0.4.

BitTorrent and other file sharing apps use various techniques, like NAT traversal, hole punching, etc to get connections through routers and firewalls.  For example, if one party is behind a router/firewall and the other party is not, then the two apps first try to connect to each other in one direction, and if that fails then they reverse roles - client becomes server and server becomes client - and they try again.  If that still fails, they could then connect to a middleman server that both parties have access to, and let it delegate the connections.